# check if any members of a set start with a given prefix string in Python

Tags: python, set

In Python, I have a `set` of filenames and a given directory name (in a loop).

Both the filenames in the set and the given directory name are in the same namespace, e.g. I simply want to see if there are **any member strings in the set that start with a given string** / prefix.

What's the Python way to see if any filenames in a set start with a given directory prefix?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the builtin [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
any(x.startswith(prefix) for x in your_set)
```

This gives you a simple `True` or `False` -- depending on whether any of the items meets the criteria.  If you want to know which element met your criteria, then you'll need [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
next((x for x in your_set if x.startswith(prefix)),None)
```

Of course, this only returns 1 element that meets your criteria -- If you need all of them, then see the [answer by jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617595/748858).

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over all the set elements - you can get a lsit of these names by simply doing:

```
results = [element for element in your_set if element.startswith(your_prefix)]
```

But by doing that you loose the fast acces set has to elements - since it is done with the hashes of strigns it stores. So, there is no fast way, using pure sets, to quickly check for substrings in its elements.